# Add href hyperlink to row or field in datatable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've seen a lot of questions about this, however I cannot seem to get it working.

I have a datatable but I cannot get it to work. I use python-flask with bootstrap and I change a pandas dataframe to a html table with to_html().

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="dataTables-example"><thead>
<tr style="text-align: right;">
  <th>id</th>
  <th>user</th>
  <th>status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and at the bottom of the body I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({

        "bDestroy": true,
       "deferRender": true,
       "columns": [
          { "data": "id" }, 
          { 
             "data": "weblink",
             "render" : function(data, type, row, meta){
                if(type === 'display'){
                   return $('<a>')
                      .attr('href', data)
                      .text(data)
                      .wrap('<div></div>')
                      .parent()
                      .html();

                } else {
                   return data;
                }
             }
          } 
       ]
    });
});
</script>
```

I've looked at a lot of awnsers however they all contain the data as json in the javascript while my data is already in the html.

Comment: Could we see the data in the original DataFrame?

Comment: Why the `pandas` tag?

Comment: Why the `python` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`columnDefs`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) when you have a DOM `<table>` and only need to target one or  few columns :

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
  destroy: true,
  deferRender: true,
  columnDefs: [{ 
    targets: 0, //<-- index of column that should be rendered as link
    render : function(data, type, row, meta){
      if (type === 'display'){
         return $('<a>')
           .attr('href', data)
           .text(data)
           .wrap('<div></div>')
           .parent()
           .html();
      } else {
         return data;
      }
     }
  }] 
})
```

It works here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j9ez0sbj/**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the jsfiddle example, else it would have taken me a long time to find out dataTables.rowReorder.js was a seperate script for using this functionality.

Comment: I changed the .text to .text('myurl?id=' + data); do you know how I just display the data (id) instead of the entire url?

Comment: hey @user3605780 -  `.attr('href', 'myurl?id=' + data)`  and leave `.text(data)`  ...? It is the `href` you want to change.

Comment: Yes you're right. To fast with asking before double checking. Thanks for the help it's working now. The only thing I would like to know if it is possible to make the entire field clickable or do I need to add a clickable image?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 columns in your html table but only define 2 columns in your initialization.

From datatables documentation for the [columns initialization option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns):

> Note that if you use columns to define your columns, you must have an entry in the array for every single column that you have in your table (these can be null if you don't wish to specify any options).

Depending on what your intent is, at the very least you need to add a definition for the third column, so something like this:

```
"columns": [
      { "data": "id" }, 
      { 
         "data": "weblink",
         "render" : function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
               return $('<a>')
                  .attr('href', data)
                  .text(data)
                  .wrap('<div></div>')
                  .parent()
                  .html();

            } else {
               return data;
            }             
         }
      },
      { "data": "status" } // Third column definition added 
   ]
```